# Creating a process tree

Tags: c, linux, recursion, fork, waitpid

The following program should create processes tree of depth `K` with `N` children on each node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void spawnNodes(int curLevel, int levelLimit, int childrenNumber, 
                int nodeNumber, int offset)
{
    if (curLevel == levelLimit)
        exit(0);

    curLevel++;
    printf("(%d, %d) Pid: %d with parent %d\n", curLevel, nodeNumber, 
            getpid(), getppid());

    for (int i = 0; i < childrenNumber; i++)
    {
        pid_t childPid = fork();
        if (childPid == -1)
        {
            perror("Couldn't create process");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (childPid == 0)
        {
            spawnNodes(curLevel, levelLimit, childrenNumber, offset + i, 
                       offset + i);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int levelLimit, children;
    scanf("%d %d", &levelLimit, &children);

    spawnNodes(0, levelLimit, children, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

At a first glance it may look correct. However, there is a strange behavior that I don't understand. The first son of the process 1 goes 1 level deeper at it's last son.

This is what I mean:

```
p1--p2---p3--exit(0)
     \---p4--exit(0)
      \--p5--p6--exit(0)
```

I have discovered this while debugging in `gdb`. Also, this is the output for a binary tree of depth `2`:

```
(1, 0) Pid: 5562 with parent 2835
(2, 0) Pid: 5563 with parent 5562
(2, 1) Pid: 5566 with parent 5563
(2, 1) Pid: 5569 with parent 5562
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

If you want to create `N` children to one process do not have the creating process  `wait()` after having created the 1st child.

---

To better understand what is going on change this

```
if (curLevel == levelLimit)
  exit(0);
```

to be

```
if (curLevel == levelLimit) 
  pause();
```

This change will let each child live on until it explicitly gets killed. Doing so *no* call to `wait()` will return beforehand. This way you see that each parent creates exactly one child only.

Comment: Now I've got an even stranger behavior. Take a look at this snippet: http://pastebin.com/uVmJS4gb. This is the output: http://pastebin.com/WfC1DeKK. Which is not a tree. Closer to a tree than the last version, but not a tree yet.